# How to work with dynamic parameters in TeamCity?

Tags: git, sonarqube, bitbucket, teamcity

I am working on integration of `BitBucket`, `TeamCity` and `SonarQube`. My scenario is as follows:

1. A developer starts a new PR or changes an existing one;
2. `TeamCity` starts building the PR automatically;
3. `TeamCity` posts the analysis results to `SonarQube` via [SonarQube Runner](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration) with `-Dsonar.branch.name=%teamcity.build.branch%`;
4. `BitBucket` requests the analysis details from `SonarQube` by the branch name and displays them on the PR page.

So the problem is that I cannot deduce the name of the branch the PR is based on. Here is what happens:

1. I configure `TeamCity` to listen to the `+:refs/pull-requests/*/from` reference in the `VCS` branch specification;
2. When `TeamCity` discovers a new PR it starts a build
3. **The name of the branch (`teamcity.build.branch`) gets to be equal to the number of the PR** (because of the asterisk in the reference);
4. `BitBucket` cannot retrieve the analysis details by the PR's branch name, because they are stored in `SonarQube` under the name which is equal to the number of the PR and not the name of the branch.

Solution 1 (dynamic parameters):

1. to define some sort of a dynamic parameter;
2. to assign a value to the parameter in one of the build steps;
3. to use that value to post analysis results to `SonarQube`.

Solution 2:

1. to listen to both references: `+:refs/pull-requests/*/from` and `+:refs/heads/*`;
2. to set up a `VCS` trigger that listens to `+:refs/heads/*` only;
3. to fail the build in the first build step if no pull-request reference for the current branch is found.

It does not seem like a good solution.

So it seems to me that the solution should be something like:

1. to make TeamCity trigger a build when a new PR is found (the way it works now);
2. to make it to figure out the correct branch name (by commit hash) and store it in a dynamic parameter;
3. to pass the value of this parameter into `SonarQube` Runner (`-Dsonar.branch.name=%dynamic.branch...%`)

I read the [documentation about TeamCity predefined branch parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-Branch-RelatedParameters), but have not found anything helpful.

Please help me figure out how to config it.

Comment: "This is impossible to achieve, because TeamCity does not provide dynamic parameters" it's not correct

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, please share the link, I was unable to find it myself.

Comment: you able to create\change new parameter dynamicaly with [Build Script Interaction with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, Thank you for showing it to me, I have never encountered it. It is exactly what I need. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a dedicated service message in your build script, you can dynamically update build parameters of the build right from a build step (the parameters need to be defined in the Parameters section of the build configuration).

[Build Script Interaction with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter)

```
echo ##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff']
```

P.S. `echo` is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

Configuration parameters (no prefix)

```
 Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='ParameterName' value='NewValue']"
```

Environment variables (defined by the env. prefix)

```
 Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.ParameterName' value='NewValue']"
```

System properties (defined by the system. prefix)

```
 Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.ParameterName' value='NewValue']"
```

e.g.

1. Parameter should be available in parameters section of build
   [image: parameter should be available in parameters section of build]
2. Add "Write-Host" to update the parameter value
   [image]